# Generate A Blank Image From Width And Height In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image, random

I want to make a blank canvas bitmap image with a certain width and height, in VB.NET, I am using Visual Studio 2017, with a Windows Forms Application, and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I tried creating a new bitmap image based of a new image with parameters of the width and height, but that didn't really work out. I tried to have a look and the expected parameters, but it didn't really show me much.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim Image = New Bitmap(New Image(WidthInput.Value, HeightInput.Value))
End Sub
```

I expect the result to be an image with a width of `WidthInput.Value` and a height of `HeightInput.Value`, that is pure white, or any other colour.

Comment: Kind of guessed _that one_. Now that I _done some more research_, I finally know, it's just that **Visual Studio only told me one way of _filling out_ the parameters**.

Answer (score 2):

I done some more research, and found I can [pass the width and height through the Bitmap constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_). Width and height need to be type of `Int32`.

Comment: Like this: `New Bitmap(W, H)`, type needs to be `Int32`.